# How to calculate definite integral of $e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory

I have a random variable $X$ with $\ln(X)$ distributed $N(0, 1)$. I want $\mathbb{P}(X \ge 2)$

I've deduced this is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\ln 2} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy$.

I've looked into the error function and see methods exist for up to $\infty$. I could use some help in seeing how to reduce this to some closed form. I have that $F_Y(y)$, the CDF, for a normally distributed r.v $Y$ is the error function.

Edit: A numerical answer will also do.

Comment: There is no closed form. There are many elementary functions such that their indefinite integrals cannot be written in terms of elementary functions, and $e^{-x^2}$ and friends are in that class. That's why the books have tables listing numerical values of the CDF of a normally distributed random variable.

Comment: My job is to at the very least compute a value to this @JyrkiLahtonen (some value), so I can compare to those tabulations.

Comment: You can compute it to high accuracy with any computer algebra system. Via Wolfram Mathematica I got $0.755891404214417265994960693521\ldots$.

Comment: If a numerical answer is all you want, then any common software package can do this.

Comment: If you want something to compare to those tables you can use the known value 
$$\frac1{\sqrt2+pi}\int_{-\infty}^0e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=\frac12,$$ and then for example use the Taylor expansion of $e^t$ to estimate the remaining part $\int_0^{\ln 2}$. Other methods for numerical evaluation are probably known, but that is something anyone can use after Calculus 102.

Comment: I think this is the error function $\Phi$ evaluated at $\ln 2\approx 0.693$. You might find the values in the tables of some mathematical book or a modern approach would be to plug it in Wolfram or Python.

Comment: Tables (Schaum's Fifth Edition) up to the second digit ($0.69\approx0.693$) say $0.7549$ while  Wolfram says Gary's value.

Comment: In my previous comment a backslash was accidentally replaced by a +-sign. The layout of the Finnish keyboard is such that a backslash is produced by the combo `AltGr +` :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the error function and it's relation to the complementary error function to arrive at the following...

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{z}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z}e^{-t^2}dt$$

$$\therefore\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt2 \ln2}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{-\sqrt2 \ln2}e^{-t^2}dt$$

Applying the substitution $t=-\frac{u}{\sqrt2}$ yields;

$$\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\ln2}^{-\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\ln2}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$

$$\therefore \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\ln2}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\ln2}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}\int_{0}^{\ln2}u^{2n}du$$

So the integral in question is equal to;

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\ln2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(\ln2)^{2n}}{2^nn!\cdot(2n+1)}$$